# Cytoscape 2.8.2 Launch With Errors

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am very new to Cytoscape, which I need for my thesis and I need to use this specific version.
I installed it on my Laptop and on the installation instructions said to install the Java 2 Runtime Environment, version 1.4.2 or higher.
I could not install this version or SE 5/6 so eventually I installed the version 17.0.1. I launched cytoscape 2.8.2 using the following commands on cmd on Ubuntu

```
chmod a+x cytoscape.sh
./cytoscape.sh
```

I get these errors:
[cmd errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL5xE.jpg), [cytoscape error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpiBw.jpg)

Ubuntu details:
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS,

Release:    20.04,

Running on VMware® Workstation 16 Player, v16.1.0 build-17198959

Comment: It seems like you have some java related errors. Just try googling those error messages and to understand what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Wow. That's a really old version of Cytoscape! That version was released 10 years ago. There is no way it will run with Java 17 (the newest LTS version). In fact, the current release of Cytoscape won't run on Java 17. We are working on that support for Cytoscape 3.10.

Your best bet is installing the oldest Java possible. It might simply not be possible without having a 10 year old machine that hasn't been updated and still runs.